# Spring Integration Exception Handling

Tags: exception, spring-integration

What is the concept behind exception handling in Spring Integration or any other EAI framework: Are they treated as a Message?

Lets say that a JMS timeout exception was thrown from `jms-outbound-gateway`. Now it has to be moved all the way upto the parent custom gateway `addEmployeeGateway` which defines a method called `addEmployee` which throws a custom exception called `SystemDownException`. These  two components are connected through request and reply channels and thats the only medium of communication. Does it mean that Exceptions are also treated as messages?

Also, if i had to map the JMS timeout exception to my custom exception `SystemDownException` and rethrow the `SystemDownException` how and where would i achieve this. I dont want to use an `errorchannel`.

Answer (score 0):

The general mechanism for handling exceptions is an `error-channel` on the inbound (or some intermediate) endpoint; the `ErrorMessage` payload has `failedMessage` and `cause` properties.

The mechanism is similar to `try {...} catch {...}` in Java.

> I dont want to use an errorchannel.

Alternatively, you can configure a [custom request handler advice](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#custom-advice) on the JMS outbound gateway; there, you can do whatever you want, including throwing your `SystemDownException` after catching an exception on `callback.execute()`.